# How do "States" work in Flash Builder and Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, flash-builder, states

I'm a little unclear as to how "states" work in Flex and Flash Bilder 4. Are states like "frames" in Flash Pro, or am I getting them wrong?

How would I show difference "screens" to a user? (login, admin panel - settings, main menu)I take it that I need to use states, but I haven't figured out how to do so. Should I be using Actionscript somewhere, something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

States are a way of grouping layout & property settings, so that when a particular state is active, all of it's associated properties are set to state specific values.

By doing this, you can show the user a different layout of a view by setting up different states and  then applying different state properties for components of that view.

Answer (score 0):

[it's just a kind of event system :)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf63611-7ff1.html)

Comment: +1 for the link, -1 for "kind of events system" it's not really, it just sets properties in groups.

Comment: @ Slomojo : and if statechange events are a part of states concept then it's also an awesome event subsystem that helps to keep every object up to date (i mean both appearance and logic)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to watch a screencast on View States here:
http://www.firststepsinflex.com/